# Excel nested if function keeps returning false

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I am trying to categorize quantitative data into 4 categories: Low, Medium, High, Very High.

```
=IF(0.35<G2<0.554,"Low",IF(0.555<G2<0.699,"Medium",IF(0.7<G2<0.799,"High",IF(0.35<G2<0.8,"Very High"))))
```

Does anyone know why this keeps returning "False"?

Thank you

Comment: What's the value in G2

Comment: The value for G2=0.479

Comment: You can't use two comparisons at once if you want you have to wrap it in an AND function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would be the correct syntax you're looking for. If you want multiple criteria you have to use the AND function and make single comparisons multiple times.

`=IF(AND(0.35<G2,G2<0.554),"Low",IF(G2<0.699,"Medium",IF(G2<0.799,"High",IF(G2<0.8,"Very High"))))`

Answer (score 0):

It's because `=0.35<G1<0.554` does not make sense from Excel's point of view, Excel's logic would require to make it `AND(0.35<G2,G2<0.554)`.  Nested `IF`s are difficult to read and maintain, I would suggest using a look up table as per the example below:

[image]